# PHP MySQL: Remote connection access denied from mysql_connect but from client is ok

Tags: php, mysql, remote-access

I've got problem with connection to mysql base via php, i can connect to database via mysql client application without any problems but mysql_connect all the time showing access denied.

- I've got local mysql server on windows
- static ip
- opened port 3306
- added port rules in windows firewall (also tried with firewall disabled)
- mysql user with all granted (flushed privileges)
- binded address in my.ini to my server ip

and f.e. application dbforge studio for mysql (mysql client app) can connect without any problems and mysql_connect in php can't.

```
$sql_connect = mysql_connect("mystatic_ip", "user", "pass");
echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(). "\n";
$sql_selected = mysql_select_db("database");
```

Another strange thing is that i'm trying to connect from different network/machine and the error displays 'localhost'

```
    1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: where are running the php script and where is the database

Comment: use `mysqli` or `PDO` because `mysql` is depricated. php run from user (www-data) but don't have access to socet mysql. Or you try connect to mysql remotaly don't localhost. and server by default settings, you don't have access.

Comment: php is on outside server, different hosting, everything works there fine, i can connect via mysql_connect to different databases but not to mine. My database is in windows machine mysql server with static ip and :3306

Comment: mysqli is giving the same answer: Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 1045 Debugging error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)